How to sign Safe Transactions using AWS KMS?
Currently I created a program such that different entities (multi-sig) will check that a transaction follows some requirements before being executed using the protocol-kit by Gnosis Safe.
Some entities do not want to use a private key directly and want to use AWS KMS instead. Following the blog, I managed to sign and send a transaction using a normal EOA but I'm currently struggling when integrating safe since I'm not sure what I need to sign for the transaction. Any guidance would help, thanks.

You would need to get the hash of the transaction, which can be done via the SDK, and sign this hash using the method provided in the blog post; the Ethereum address managed by the AWS KMS should be an owner of the Safe in question.
Let me know if that answered your question, and if it did, please feel free to mark it as solved.
Thanks in advance! Best; Louis
